# "incomplete type is not allowed" in a C program

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm trying to learn network programming in C, I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define BUFFLEN 1024

int main() {
    int sockfd, clientfd;
    char buffer[BUFFLEN];
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    return 0;
}
```

I use VS code as my main IDE, but as smart as it usually is, it just doesn't seem to work in this case, although I'm probably just doing something wrong.

The above code gives me this error
"incomplete type is not allowed"

I cannot access the 'hints' structure, the code completion doesn't work and I have no idea why...
I have included all the needed header files, or at least I think so.

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I have tried googling for a solution but haven't found anything of use...

Comment: The title says "incomplete type is not allowed", but the post says "incomplete command no allowed".  I'm guessing the title is correct.  In that case, I'd say it wants the definition of `struct addrinfo`, but it's not getting it from the included header files.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, assuming it uses POSIX C libraries, and not Microsoft WinSock2 libraries. Perhaps it is a problem in the IDE.

Comment: @TomKarzes `struct addrinfo` should be defined by `#include <netdb.h>`.

Comment: @IanAbbott isn't it opaque?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, at least with POSIX libraries.  I wonder what version of `netdb.h` it's picking up...

Comment: @gulpr No, it contains at least a documented set of members.

Comment: @TomKarzes Sorry for the oversight, I made a typo, the correct error is "incomplete type is not allowed"

Comment: @gulpr I'm not sure but *maybe* the opacity (or otherwise) of the `addrinfo` structure depends on the compiler standard/version. There is a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/11vwkgf/intellisense_on_vscode_inside_wsl_seems_to_be/) that suggests using `-std=gnu17` fixes the Intelli-Nonsense issue.

Comment: It may be because Intellisense does not know which feature test macros have been defined by default. Or if this error is from the actual compiler, rather than just information from Intellisense, perhaps OP will need to define the appropriate feature test macro in the project's C preprocessor settings.

Comment: @BrewsLee, yes, you are supposed to edit the question to add corrections, not leave it in a comment.  Done.

Comment: I would not rely on the IDE code parser to correctly identify errors.  It requires a lot of information that may not be available to it, such as what pre-processor macros are set for conditional compilation of the headers and where it should search for headers to pick the same ones that your actual build is using.  If it compiles without error, move on, or spend your time setting up the editor to "know" as much as the compiler does when built.

Comment: Try adding `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`  before the first `#include` line.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler tell you which type is incomplete and/or point at a line of code?

Comment: VS Code is multiplatform... Which compiler version and OS are you using?

Comment: @arfneto, I'm using gcc version 11.4.0 and POP!_OS